# How do I use format in table to show the first sign of a capital letter?

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2003

Welcome,

I would like to display first sign in table of a capital letter.

I'm don't looking for input mask for new data, but format for existing data.

I have inside existing table people Names in like bellow:

```
xyz
yzz
zzz
```

I would like display

```
Xyz
Yzz
Zzz
```

Answer (score 1):

When you read the data out of the database you can use `StrConv` to convert the value to "Proper Case", meaning the first letter of *every* word is capitalised and every other letter is lower case. An example is below, this will work within queries and VB.

```
StrConv( FieldName , 3 )
```

This works quite well for names (*most of the time*), here's some examples, including a few that will fail:

```
john               -> John
john smith         -> John Smith
JOHN SMITH         -> John Smith
jOhN sMiTh         -> John Smith
jOHN sMITH         -> John Smith
john de smith      -> John De Smith      (Error: expected "John de Smith")
john mcsmith       -> John Mcsmith       (Error: expected "John McSmith")
john van der smith -> John Van Der Smith (Error: expected "John van der Smith")
```

A solution that handles edge cases more effectively requires a custom fuction to do the work.